# Motor Vehicle key detection

Tags: bmw

I am creating a system whereby when a key is inserted to the ignition cylinder of a car without the my knowledge i am notified. Am ok with the whole preocess except how to actualize the detection part. What can i use to detect that a key has been inserted? which sensor and how?

Comment: Microswitch operated by the key entering the slot

Answer (score 1):

Which exact year and model of car?

Most cars already have a microswitch in the ignition barrel that detects the key. This is then used to issue warnings to the driver such as to warn them when they've left the key in or to turn interior lights off etc.

Sometimes it is an actual switch on/in the barrel or the switch in part of the actual ignition switch on the back of the barrel.

It would be very easy to tap into this circuit as they usually are just a simple switch to positive or Ground.

Comment: It may be a low voltage as it can go directly to the body ecu...